# Symfony console component categories

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

Is there a way to put commands into a category for the Symfony Console component? Currently the commands are listed like so:

```
Available commands:
  create-droplets  Create droplets
  help             Displays help for a command
  list             Lists commands
```

What I would want is something like this:

```
Available commands:
  Server:
     create-droplets  Create droplets

  Default:
     help             Displays help for a command
     list             Lists commands
```

I think this is currently being done in Laravel with artisan but I am wondering if this is also possible with the Symfony Console component.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to read about Symfony Console Commands: http://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html

That being said, you can group commands. Syntax:

group:command_name

In your case it would be:

1. server:create-droplets

   `$this->setName('server:create-droplets')
           ->setDescription('Create droplets')`
2. default:help

   `$this->setName('default:help')
           ->setDescription('Displays help for a command')`
3. default:list

   `$this->setName('default:list')
           ->setDescription('Lists commands')`